# MS CRM: Check the status of a child workflow

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, workflow

I am designing a few workflows. The main workflow calls some child workflow. If the child workflows fail I need to wait for a time period and then rerun that child workflow. If it fails again send a task to a queue.
I am having troubles checking the status of the child workflow. When it fails I am stopping the child workflow with the status cancelled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom workflow step that queries async operation table and checks state of child workflow.

Query to get state of child workflow:

```
﻿<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<fetch distinct='false' no-lock='false' mapping='logical' page='1' count='100'>
  <entity name='asyncoperation'>
    <attribute name='statuscode' />
    <filter type='and'>
      <filter type='and'>
        <condition attribute='correlationid' operator='eq' value='{Correlation ID of workflow>' />
        <condition attribute='name' operator='eq' value='NAME OF CHILD WORKFLOW' />
      </filter>
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

It's sample query, and matches child by name and correlation id. It will work if you have only one call to child workflow.

Here you can find a list of state values for async processes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309288.aspx

Then main workflow steps would look like:

- call child workflow
- wait some time
- call custom step to check status of child workflow
- if child status is ok - carry on with main
- if not add logic to handle failure